# Script to know the edit history of a cell google sheet

Tags: javascript, excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I´m working with a file with multiple people and i want to do a script that tells me the person how modify that cell and the time when that happend, i only need the email user that did the last change and the time [example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92nHf.png),

I got this so far, this gets me the email user but no the time stamp.

```
function history_version() { 
  var thisSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet1 = thisSS.getSheetByName('Data'); 
  var specialCell = sheet1.getRange("A1:A5"); 
  Logger.log(htmlEmail = "Cell " + specialCell.getA1Notation() +  " edited by " + Session.getActiveUser().getEmail())

}
```

Thaks for the time

Comment: Use `Date.now()` to get a timestamp in milliseconds from epoch. Or `new Date().toLocaleString()` for the timestamp as a locale string.

Comment: Hello Mohammed, thaks for the reply, but i will need the time or the last modification not the current date, is for controling how is using the file

Comment: Do you want to store the edit history in a separate sheet or column or just want to log it?

Comment: Regarding `but i will need the time or the last modification not the current date, is for controling how is using the file`, what I understand from your question is that `history_version` is called by a trigger, like `onEdit` or `onChange`, so using `new Date()` will return the date at which the edit is made. Isn't this what you want to accomplish?

Comment: I have 10 files that have the same structure and i want to know who is ussing that file (the user can only edit in one cell), i will loop to every file and ask the history version of that cell and log the output. The perfect output will be something like this 'email of the user, last edited on)

Comment: How are you currently executing `history_version`?

Comment: Nop, the only code that i hace is the one above, with that the only output that i get is the email, but not the last modification date

Comment: My question was `How are you currently executing history_version?`. That is, are you doing it directly from the editor? Or is it attached to an `onEdit` trigger or similar?

Comment: Yes, atm i´m running the script manually from the editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

If you fire your function through an [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger, and not manually from the editor, you can get the actual [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) an edit was made:

```
function onEdit() {
  var thisSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = thisSS.getSheetByName('Data');
  var specialCell = sheet1.getRange("A1:A5");
  var now = new Date();
  Logger.log("Edited by " + Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail() + " at " + now);
}
```

#### Note:

I used [getEffectiveUser](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#geteffectiveuser) instead of [getActiveUser](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getactiveuser) since the latter might not be available in this context ([simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)). Another option would be to [install the trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) instead (that will be necessary if you are to access services that require authorization).